# Lambda construction performance and static lambda?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, lambda, static

Consider the following code:

```
// Classic version
template <class It>
It f(It first, It last)
{
    using value_type = It::value_type;
    auto lambda = [](value_type x){return x > 10 && x < 100;};
    return std::find_if(first, last, lambda);
}

// Static version
template <class It>
It f(It first, It last)
{
    using value_type = It::value_type;
    static auto lambda = [](value_type x){return x > 10 && x < 100;};
    return std::find_if(first, last, lambda);
}
```

Is there any performance difference between the two? What's the construction time of a lambda function? Is the static version better in terms of performances because the lambda is constructed only once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constructing a capture-less lambda is similar to constructing an empty `struct`. A modern compiler should be able to optimize that away completely.

As an example, see the assembly output for this simple program:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  auto l = [](int i){ return i*i; };
  return l(argc);
}
```

Assembly (gcc 5.2.0, starting with `-O1`, [LIVE](http://goo.gl/rC9VYX)):

```
main:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    imull   %edi, %eax
    ret
```

As you can see, no remnants of any lambdas, etc. It was completely inlined.

While your particular use-case may need more analysis, likely there will be no measurable difference between static and non-static lambdas.